# Lazy images load perfectly but have to reload abruptly when they reappear in the viewport

Tags: reactjs, image, performance, lazy-loading

I have managed to lazy load a long list a images in React, with a loader. It works well. However, when scrolling back up, the images have disappeared and have to reload abruptly - without the smooth transition - to go back on screen. Long story short, the user experience is crap. Normally, already loaded images should remain displayed.

How to fix such a performance issue? Is it because of loading="lazy" native img attribute?

Here is a sandbox that reproduce the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-tdd-qlf9h?file=/src/App.tsx

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components";

interface ImageProps {
  src: string;
  lazy?: boolean;
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
  alt?: string;
}

const Root = styled.div<{ width: number; height: number }>`
  border-radius: 8px;
  width: ${({ width }) => (width ? `${width}px` : "100%")};
  height: ${({ height }) => (height ? `${height}px` : "100%")};
  position: relative;
`;

const loading = keyframes`
  0% {background-position: -468px 0;}
  100% {background-position: 900px 0;}
`;

const Placeholder = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #f6f7f9;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: ${loading};
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #f6f7f9 0%,
    rgba(175, 164, 164, 0.11) 20%,
    #f6f7f9 40%,
    #f6f7f8 80%,
    #f6f7f9 100%
  );
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 800px 400px;
  height: 100%;
`;

const Picture = styled.img<{ loaded: boolean }>`
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  opacity: ${({ loaded }) => (loaded ? 1 : 0)};
  transition: opacity 1s;
`;

export default function Image({
  src,
  width,
  height,
  lazy = false,
  alt
}: ImageProps) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current && ref.current.complete) {
      setLoaded(true);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Root width={width} height={height}>
      <Placeholder aria-hidden="true" />
      <Picture
        loading={lazy ? "lazy" : null}
        src={src}
        alt={alt}
        width={width}
        height={height}
        ref={ref}
        onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)}
        loaded={loaded}
      />
    </Root>
  );
}
```

Bonus question: how to apply a padding to all images directly from the Wrapper container (the one that has display: flex + flex-wrap:wrap in App.tsx?

Comment: The app is really slow. I suggest you use virtualization this will solve the above issue as well. I analyzed the network requests after loading all images and ran a performance check the main issue for the lag is the painting which occupies a lot of time therefore you see a delay.

Comment: Isn't lazy loading supposed to solve the painting time issue by only downloading images once the user reach their position? The sandbox runs smoothly on my computer (but I have a high speed internet connection). It is sluggish in Storybook though. If I use react-virtualized, will I still need to add loading="lazy" attribute to the image?